# modifying php.ini on Windows Azure Web role by a script

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-roles

I have used a Startup script on a Web role to install PHP by using Windows Plattform Installer. Everything is ok, PHP is installed and the application works, however when I uppload large files the application generates error. I fixed it by editing the php.ini file manually and chnaged upload_max_filesize. My question is, How do I can modify php.ini file automatically (not manually) by adding som script to be executed AFTER php has been installed. I wrote "AFTER" because this script must wait until my startup script is executed completelly and php has been installed.
Thanks for your help appreciate all advices.

UPdated: 
Following is my install-php.bat file which is located in bin folder of my web role. I am not familiar with powershell. How can I translate it to powershell script?

```
ECHO "Starting PHP Installation" >> log.txt

md "%~dp0appdata"
cd "%~dp0appdata"
cd..

reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%~dp0appdata" /f

"..\MyWebpicmdline\WebPICmdLine" /Products:PHP53 /AcceptEula >>log.txt 2>>err.txt

reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local /f

ECHO "Completed PHP Installation" >> log.txt
```

Comment: you can try to use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);` as well as for upload_max_filesize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming you have a startup task with the following:

```
WebPICmdLine.exe /Products: PHP
```

You'll need to write some script that will update your php.ini file and run it after installing PHP. A possible solution would be to do this with PowerShell:

```
WebPICmdLine.exe /Products: PHP
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
powershell .\UpdatePhpIni.ps1
```

Find a script that allows you to update ini files (like [Edit Ini File](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/13594.aspx)), add it to your UpdatePhpIni.ps1 file and add the required code to modify the execution time.

Note that I'm not a PHP expert, but if I remember correctly you should configure this in the [FastCGI settings](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis/#Per-site_PHP_configuration) of IIS (I think these have priority over php.ini).

**Update:** Here is what your script should look like with the FastCGI configuration.

```
ECHO "Starting PHP Installation" >> log.txt

md "%~dp0appdata"
cd "%~dp0appdata"
cd..

reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%~dp0appdata" /f

"..\MyWebpicmdline\WebPICmdLine" /Products:PHP53 /AcceptEula >>log.txt 2>>err.txt

ECHO Updating activity timeout.
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi "/[fullPath='%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe'].activityTimeout:800"

reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local /f

ECHO "Completed PHP Installation" >> log.txt
```

Comment: thank you for your fast and usefull answer. I am not familiar with powershell. follwoing is my install-php.bat file which is located under bin folder of my web role. how do I convert it to powershell? do I need to use powershell to install php?

Comment: No need to convert your script to PowerShell or to use Powershell. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi, I soleved this problem by adding a php folder to the bin folder of the webrole and adding a php.ini file to that folder which contains the variables I want to change. Thank you Sandrino for spending your time to give an answer. your answer is correct and it helped me to find another post which in turn sovled my problem so I mark your as answer.